# Billing a customer for level of services used on azure

Tags: azure, billing

I am building a service on azure and wanted to know if there is any way to know how much resources (data downloaded or uploaded, time required to do the processing) a customer has used in a given session and what level of services they have used in order to bill them accordingly. We expose the whole framework as a service, this consists of various small levels of services, like reading the data from some external FTP server, downloading it to blob, reading the file downloaded and storing them in tables and performing some operations the data in the table, email some results from service required by the user, etc.
So, depending on what all services the customer has used, we would like to bill them accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Azure specific function that I can think of that will help you with what you want to track is [Azure Storage Logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx) which will track each and every request to Azure Storage, I'm not sure how much that is going to help you though.

I think you will have to decide exactly what you want to bill your customers for and then start tracking that yourself.  This might be items similar to what MS charges you for (tracking the size of incoming requests, counting the number of transactions and the size of data stored to Azure Storage) or maybe just some arbitrary values based on some of this information